# ocamlfind: command not found

Tags: makefile, ocaml, opam, ocamlfind

I'm running into an issue installing a package that's reliant on `ocamlfind`. I'm getting an `ocamlfind: command not found` error when running `make`.

I have installed `ocamlfind` with the OCaml package manager and have tried reinstalling using `opam reinstall ocamlfind`.

I have also tried the `eval opam config env` command to see if it updates my bin.

The output when running `make`:

```
$ make
ocamlfind ocamlc -pp "camlp4o -I lib/dcg -I lib/ipp pa_dcg.cmo pa_ipp.cmo" -w usy -thread -I lib -I lib/dcg -I lib/ipp       -c semantics.ml
/bin/sh: ocamlfind: command not found
```

The output when trying `ocamlfind`

```
$ ocamlfind
-bash: ocamlfind: command not found
```

OCaml is installed

```
$ opam install ocamlfind
[NOTE] Package ocamlfind is already installed (current version is 1.5.5).
```

and when running the `eval` command

```
$ eval 'opam config env'
CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/centos/.opam/system/lib/stublibs:/usr/lib64/ocaml/stub libs"; export CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
MANPATH="/home/centos/.opam/system/man:"; export MANPATH;
PERL5LIB="/home/centos/.opam/system/lib/perl5"; export PERL5LIB;
OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH="/home/centos/.opam/system/lib/toplevel"; export OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH;
PATH="/home/centos/.opam/system/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/centos/.local/bin:/home/centos/bin"; export PATH;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to run

```bash
eval `opam config env`
```

or using `$(...)` instead is the modern equivalent and avoids confusion between `'` and `` ` ``

```bash
eval $(opam config env)
```

This `eval` command sets the environment variables in the current shell session and exports them for use by processes run by this shell session, so it needs to be run in *every* shell session that needs those set, including each line of the Makefile that expects them to be set if the environment that runs `make` doesn't already have them set and exported.

The command you ran

> ```bash
> eval 'opam config env'
> ```

is a typo.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
sudo apt-get install ocaml-findlib
```

Comment: A little more explanation would have been very helpful. Giving a suggestion without a clarification or explanation is pretty much similar to giving a (side) comment.